# Unable to load System.Data.Linq.dll for CodeDom

Tags: c#, codedom

I am trying to dynamicaly compile code using CodeDom. I can load other assemblies, but I cannot load System.Data.Linq.dll.  I get an error:

Metadata file 'System.Data.Linq.dll' could not be found

My code looks like:

```
CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
compilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/target:library /optimize";
compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
compilerParams.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Linq.dll");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: edit request: please fix the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That may be because this assembly is stored in a different location than mscorlib is.  It should work if you provide a full path to the assembly.  The most convenient way to get the full path is to let the .NET loader do the work for you.  I would try something like this:

```
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(DataContext).Assembly.Location);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly answer, but are you sure the code is running on a machine with .NET Framework 3.5?

Comment: I'm sure he is. I'm having the exact same error, and I have both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4. :)